# Can I have an AB test with multiple steps with Split gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, ab-testing

I have a rails application and I want to use Split for AB testing.
Is there a way to keep track of multiple steps with Split? I want to keep track of users who clicked an `add to cart` button and then finalised their purchase.
Right now it seems the only way to do this is to make 2 separate tests as below,

- first one starting when the user sees the "add to cart" button and finishes when he/she clicks it
- second one starting after user clicked on the button and finishes when he finalises his/her purchase